# custom modules folder in yarn2

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I'm currently in the process of upgrading to yarn 2 and with classic yarn (yarn 1) we used to install packages in a custom folder using `--modules-folder` as described [here](https://www.caxy.com/blog/how-set-custom-location-nodemodules-path-yarn)

I don't find a equivalent option or a way to do it with yarn 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is the same thing but looks similar to the link your question provided.

For Yarn you could add a folder as follows with the following scenario:

```
├── customFolder
│   ├── build
│   ├── src
│   ├── ...
│   └── package.json
├── node_modules
├── public
├── src
├── ...
└── package.json
```

Yarn 1

```
yarn add file:./customFolder
```

Yarn 2 | Yarn 3

```
yarn add ./customFolder
```